# Transfer all data to a new phoenix cluster

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

Is there a standard way to move all apache phoenix data to a new cluster? and how long would it take to move 2 terabytes of phoenix rows?

senario:

I launched my platform using virtual servers (as its cheaper) but now I am ready to move to dedicated servers but I want to know the right way to move the data to a new cluster so my users dont hunt me down to torture me for messing up the data they trusted my platform with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All phoenix data is present as hbase tables, so the easiest way is to take a snapshot of all tables in hbase, then use hbase to copy them over.

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/57049/hbase-table-copy-from-one-cluster-to-other.html